# Как игнорировать все возможные Ошибки в файле-классе

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, python-3.5, celery

Добрый день, товарищши .
Есть у нас класс который проверяет оченьт много сервисов контейнеров и тд.тп.

```
class EnvironmentalControl():
    def check_mongo():
        <Do_some_job>
    def check_redis():
        <Do_some_job>
    .
    .
    .
```

В основном это просто проверка подключения , и если не подключается то не работает , все просто `True or False` так называемый СмокТест
Поскольку это проверка работы наших сервисов она запускается крон табом , в нутри контейнера , но ситуация какая , когда на дев сервере все не работает , не возможно отследить работу других кронтабов в этом контенере. 
Збивает лог контенера милионами строк об ошибках . 
Вопрос стоит в том как приминить концепцию

```
try:
    <Do_some_job>
except Exeption as e:
    logger.error(e)
```

К всему классу, чтоб он ловил все ошибки , произошедшие в классе и писал их просто в лог, а не выкидывл трайсбек на 1000 строк

**UPD 1**

Кое как костыльным методом сделал , трай но есть ошибки который ну просто не ловятся через `except Exeption as e: pass`

```
[2017-04-18 10:42:00,050: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: check_environment_condition[56248963-2978-4ade-aabb-357165686a36]
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM[2017-04-18 10:42:00,107: WARNING/PoolWorker-7] GET http://elk:9200/_cluster/health [status:N/A request:0.001s]
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PMTraceback (most recent call last):
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 60, in create_connection
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 733, in getaddrinfo
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PMsocket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PMDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PMTraceback (most recent call last):
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 114, in perform_request
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=self.headers, **kw)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 649, in urlopen
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 324, in increment
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    raise value
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    chunked=chunked)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 356, in _make_request
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1107, in request
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1152, in _send_request
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self.endheaders(body)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1103, in endheaders
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self._send_output(message_body)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self.send(msg)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self.connect()
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 166, in connect
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    conn = self._new_conn()
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PMurllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5c914d4da0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM[2017-04-18 10:42:00,108: WARNING/PoolWorker-7] GET http://elk:9200/_cluster/health [status:N/A request:0.001s]
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PMTraceback (most recent call last):
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 60, in create_connection
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 733, in getaddrinfo
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PMsocket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PMDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PMTraceback (most recent call last):
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 114, in perform_request
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=self.headers, **kw)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 649, in urlopen
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 324, in increment
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    raise value
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    chunked=chunked)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 356, in _make_request
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1107, in request
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1152, in _send_request
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self.endheaders(body)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1103, in endheaders
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self._send_output(message_body)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self.send(msg)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self.connect()
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 166, in connect
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    conn = self._new_conn()
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PMurllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5c9145e4a8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM[2017-04-18 10:42:00,110: WARNING/PoolWorker-7] GET http://elk:9200/_cluster/health [status:N/A request:0.001s]
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PMTraceback (most recent call last):
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 60, in create_connection
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 733, in getaddrinfo
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PMsocket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PMDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PMTraceback (most recent call last):
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 114, in perform_request
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=self.headers, **kw)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 649, in urlopen
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 324, in increment
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    raise value
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    chunked=chunked)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 356, in _make_request
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1107, in request
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1152, in _send_request
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self.endheaders(body)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1103, in endheaders
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self._send_output(message_body)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self.send(msg)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self.connect()
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 166, in connect
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    conn = self._new_conn()
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PMurllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5c9145e5f8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM[2017-04-18 10:42:00,111: WARNING/PoolWorker-7] GET http://elk:9200/_cluster/health [status:N/A request:0.001s]
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PMTraceback (most recent call last):
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 60, in create_connection
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 733, in getaddrinfo
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PMsocket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PMDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PMTraceback (most recent call last):
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 114, in perform_request
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=self.headers, **kw)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 649, in urlopen
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 324, in increment
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    raise value
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    chunked=chunked)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 356, in _make_request
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1107, in request
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1152, in _send_request
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self.endheaders(body)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1103, in endheaders
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self._send_output(message_body)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self.send(msg)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self.connect()
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 166, in connect
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    conn = self._new_conn()
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PMurllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5c9145e080>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM[2017-04-18 10:42:00,112: INFO/PoolWorker-7] Connecting to REDIS at: redis
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM[2017-04-18 10:42:00,113: INFO/PoolWorker-7] Connected to REDIS!
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM[2017-04-18 10:42:00,113: WARNING/PoolWorker-7] http://rabbit:15672/api/queues/%2Fproduction
4/18/2017 1:42:00 PM[2017-04-18 10:42:00,141: INFO/PoolWorker-7] Environment status: {'values': {'rabbit': True, 'elasticsearch': False, 'redis': True, 'api-production': True, 'api-development': False, 'postgresql': True}, 'started_time': 1492512120, 'create_at': 1492512120}
```

Comment: Т.е вам нужно организовать запись всех ошибок в лог файл целиком?

Comment: чтобы обработать неперехваченные исключения, есть `sys.excepthook` и/или можете декоратор на сам класс повесить или в метаклассе обернуть методы. Выглядит так что вы пытаетесь симптомы лечить, вместо самой проблемы. Не относится к проблеме в вопросе, но стоит упомянуть: может быть так, что в сервисе *всё* сломано, кроме той штучки, которую вы используете для проверки его здоровья (сервис не работает, но говорит, что он живой). Усложнение проверки, чтобы сделать её более реалистичной ведёт к тому, что [monitoring and QA are the same thing](https://plus.google.com/+RipRowan/posts/eVeouesvaVX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from functools import wraps

class OldEnvironmentalControl():
    def check_mongo(self):
        1/0

    def check_redis(self):
        raise AssertionError('error')


class EnvironmentalControl:
    def __init__(self, cls: object, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__cls = cls(*args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, func: callable):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as ex:
                print(ex, file=open('log.txt', 'a'))
        return wrapper

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self(getattr(self.__cls, attr))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ec = EnvironmentalControl(OldEnvironmentalControl)
    ec.check_mongo()
    ec.check_redis()
```

Comment: Не плохо проверим что с этого получится

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте декоратор к всем методам:

```
def wrap_except_exception(func):
    def temp(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except BaseException as e:
            print(e) # что-то делаем с исключением
            raise e
    return temp
```

Пример:

```
 class C:
      @wrap_except_exception
      def x(self, a):
          raise TypeError(a)
```

Comment: Варинт хорош , но не то , это добавляет зависимость. Что надо не  забыть добавить декоратор , гдето год назад видел что можно весь клас так отловить .

Comment: Ну можете в __ getatrtribute __ обворачивать функции

Comment: @Zaazik метакласс сократит количество мест, где можно забыть